# Grails 4.0.3 Multiple Datasources - Second datasource not available in service

Tags: grails

I've followed the instructions/example in the Grails Doc (https://docs.grails.org/4.0.3/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources) and it still uses the default dataSource.

My application.yml contains:

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    dbCreate: validate
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX.XX.X.XXX:XXXX:TEST
    username: username1
    password: password1
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    properties:
        jmxEnabled: true
        initialSize: 5
        maxActive: 50
        minIdle: 5
        maxIdle: 25
        maxWait: 10000
        maxAge: 600000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
        validationQuery: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
        validationQueryTimeout: 3
        validationInterval: 15000
        testOnBorrow: true
        testWhileIdle: true
        testOnReturn: false
        jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
        defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
dataSources:
    identityDb:
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@YYY.YY.YY.YYY:YYYYY:IDENT
        username: username2
        password: password2
```

And my service is defined as follows:

```
class PictureService {
    def grailsApplication
    def assetResourceLocator
    static dataSource = "identityDb"

    def getPictures( identifications ) {
        // Loop through all ids
        for( i in identifications ) {
            //try {
                Sql sql = Sql.newInstance( dataSource )
    ...
```

It throws this stack dump:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
        at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

When I dump out the connection string information for dataSource, I can see that it's the first datasource listed and not the identityDb datasource. I'm not using domain classes or GORM and am just writing the SQL directly. Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like the Grails Documentation that you reference suggests that the bean would be `dataSource_identityDb`, not just `identityDb`.  I have not tried it though.

Comment: Thanks @dspies. Your comment got me on the right track. I've updated my issue to show what I did to get it working.

Comment: you are most welcome, but it is customary to upvote an answer or comment instead of a thanks.  And if you solved your question, add an answer with what you did and mark it as accepted instead of editing the question, that will help others who come to this in the future. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit / Update

I changed my service to the following and it's working correctly now. I thought I had tried this before but I must not have gotten the correct combination of things in place.

Note that the application.yml did not change.

class PictureService {
def grailsApplication
def assetResourceLocator
def dataSource_identityDb

```
def getPictures( identifications ) {
    // Loop through all ids
    for( i in identifications ) {
        try {
            Sql sql = Sql.newInstance( dataSource_identityDb )
```

...
Also, this is different that what is listed in the official docs for using a second datasource in Grails 4.0.3.